# CryptoNote features in other cryptocurrencies

Tags: cryptonote, ring-signatures, cryptonight

How many CryptoNote based currencies exist today?

Have ring signatures appeared in any cryptocurrencies that are not based on CryptoNote?

How many CryptoNote coins are not using a CryptoNight based PoW?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's less than a couple dozen CN based currencies. See http://mapofcoins.com/bytecoin.

Shadowcash tried to implement ring signatures on a Bitcoin code base. See https://shnoe.wordpress.com/2016/02/11/de-anonymizing-shadowcash-and-oz-coin/.

To my knowledge, no non-CN coin uses Cryptonight. -- Oops, I misread that last question, see lethos3's answer to that one below.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful coin map and de-anonymizing paper. My third question (answered by @lethos3) was about CryptoNote coins using something other than CryptoNight, not about non CryptoNotes using CryptoNight.

Comment: Yep, I misread, sorry. I pointed to lethos3's answer.

Answer (score 11):

CryptoNote coins that do not use standard CryptoNight:

[Boolberry](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=577267.0) - Uses `Wild Keccak` instead of CryptoNight;

[Pebblecoin](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=909624.0) - Used a POW algorithm named `Boulderhash` in the POW mining phase, it required 13 GB of RAM to mine but it has since switched to DPOS;

[AEON](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=641696.0) - Uses a modified Cryptonight algo named `Cryptonight-Lite`.

Comment: I wish I could mark both answered correct as you both answered different parts of my question